# fopen is not returning address, program crashes

Tags: c, function, pointers, segmentation-fault, fopen

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MYAPP MyApp;

    MyApp = (struct MyApp*)malloc(sizeof(struct MyApp));

    MyApp->maxMovieYear = 0;
    MyApp->maxMovieNum = 0;

    MyApp->myYearTree = CreateTreeYear();
    MyApp->myTree = CreateTree();

    MyApp = read_data(argv,MyApp);


    int exit=FALSE;
    int command;
    char title[256];
    int year;
    int imdbID;
    char posterlink[512];

    printf(">>>Welcome to Movie Analysis at IMDB<<< \n");


    while (!exit)
    {

        printf("\n-Menu-\n\
1. Display the full index of movies\n\
2. Display the movies where their title contains a specific keyword\n\
3. Display the year with maximum number of movies\n\
4. Exit\n\
Option:");



        if(MyApp == NULL){
            exit = TRUE;
            printf("\nCannot locate the file!");
            break;
        }


        YearWithMostMovies(MyApp->myYearTree ,MyApp);
        scanf("%d", &command);
        fflush(stdin);
        char searchSong[512];
        switch (command)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("Movie Index\n-------------\n");
            display_index(MyApp->myTree);
            break;
        case 2:

            printf("Please enter the movie you want to see: ");
            scanf("%s",searchSong);
            display_movies_keyword(MyApp->myTree,searchSong);

            break;
        case 3:
            most_popular_year_movies(MyApp);

            break;
        case 4:
            exit = TRUE;
            break;
        default:
            printf("command not recognized\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}




MYAPP read_data(char *argv[],MYAPP MyApp){

    FILE *outfile = fopen(argv[1],"r");

    AVLTree newNode = NULL;
    if(outfile == NULL)
    {
        printf("File does not exist...\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    int delimiterCount = 0;
    char inputData[2001];

    while((fgets(inputData,2001,outfile)) != NULL)
    {

        int len = strlen(inputData);

        if (len >= 0 && inputData[len-1] == '\n') 
            inputData[--len] = '\0';

        AVLTree temp = NULL;

        //initialize the newNode
        temp = (struct tree*)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
        temp->height = 0;
        temp->left = NULL;
        temp->right = NULL;


        char* token = strtok(inputData, ",");


        strcpy(temp->title,token);
        while (token != NULL)
        {
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");//reading the rest of the tokens with strtok

            delimiterCount++;

            switch (delimiterCount)  // this switch orders the tokens by their places
            {
            case 1:
                strcpy(temp->year,token);
                break;
            case 2:
                strcpy(temp->imdbID,token);
                break;
            case 3:
                strcpy(temp->posterlink,token);
                break;
            }
        }
        newNode = temp;

        MyApp->myTree = InsertElement(newNode,MyApp->myTree);
        int x = atoi(newNode->year);
        MyApp->myYearTree = InsertElementYear(x,MyApp->myYearTree);
        delimiterCount = 0;

    }
    fclose(outfile);
    return MyApp;
}
```

My struct definitions are:

```
typedef struct tree * AVLTree;
typedef struct year *AVLYear;[enter image description here][1]
struct tree{

    char title[512];
    char posterlink[1024];
    char imdbID[512];
    char year[512];

    struct tree* left;
    struct tree* right;
    int height;
};

struct MyApp{
    AVLTree myTree;
    AVLYear myYearTree;
    int maxMovieYear;
    int maxMovieNum;
};
typedef struct MyApp* MYAPP;

typedef struct year *AVLYear;
struct year
{
    int year;
    int num;
    AVLYear left;
    AVLYear right;
    int height;
};
```

when i am trying to get filename as argument fopen returns me this

```
**<msvcrt!_iob+96>**
```

what might be causing this problem?

my aim is to get the data from a file and put it in 2 different avltree's, i keep my trees in another struct called **MYAPP** to pass between functions easily. can it be the problem?

i could not see the cause of this error.

Edit: i am using my own header files for struct definitions and functions. also including:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "AVLTree.h"
#include "AVLYear.h"
```

thanks.

Comment: Maybe try `perror("filename");` (replace `"filename"` with the name you are using) to have the runtime library help you diagnose the issue?

Comment: `fopen` either returns 0 upon error or a pointer to an open file structure. _That open file structure has no meaning to you_. So whatever it is, it is.

Comment: i tried to add `perror(argv[1]);` says no error. what else might be the issue. it was working before i use MYAPP

Comment: It seems that what you see is the interpretation of your debugger of the pointer. It means it points to some symbol "+96 bytes".

Comment: `if (len >= 0 && inputData[len-1] == '\n')` -->>  `if (len >=0 && inputData[len-1] == '\n') ` (preferred: `inputData[strcspn(inputData, "\r\n")] = 0;`

Comment: 1) missing includes 2) put the structure definitions **before** the rest of the program.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are running the program in your debugger. When you come at the `fopen` statement/call, the debugger shows you what `fopen` returned.

remember that `fopen` returns zero upon error, or a pointer to an open file structure. Since it does not return zero, it must have returned a pointer.

But your debugger wants to tell you where it is pointing to, and that is to the symbol `msvcrt!_iob` offset with 96 bytes. The seems like a valid structure, `iob` meaning something like "I/O  buffer", or whatever the Microsoft programmer intended for that abreviation.

Conclusion: *there is no error.*